# How do you code unity ui button touch controls to receive an input?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile, touch-event

I have a right, left and up button on the screen (its a 2D game). I am trying to figure out how to write a script so that when the user clicks the buttons, they receive the input and either move the player right left or up. I have watched some tutorials on Youtube but they are from a couple of years ago and are out of date and don't work for me. Could anyone send me a script or tell me how to code it (C#) so that it can recognise the touch input?

Comment: You can use Raycast, or Unity Callbacks ```OnMounsDown()``` and ```OnMouseDown()```

Answer (score 0):

Functions [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html), [OnMouseUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html), [OnMouseDrag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html), [OnMouseUpAsButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUpAsButton.html) etc. work excellent not only on PC but on Android, too.

But don't forget than you must add BoxCollider2d to the pbject to make these functions work:)